# Why SIVP Is Worst Case Problem?

Tags: lattice-crypto

I just started to study lattice Cryptography.

I'm now studying worst-case to average-case reduction for SIS.

In  [previous question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/13289/what-does-worst-case-hardness-mean-in-lattice-based-cryptography), "worst means any and average means random".

And I wonder why the Shortest Independent Vectors Problem(SIVP) is the worst-case problem.

And, does SIVP means that

"For **'any'** given lattice basis **B**, it is hard to find n linearly independent short vectors in **L(B)**"?

The definitions that I saw didn't have the word **'any'**.

Does the word **'any'** is involved in the sentence even though it is not explicitly mentioned?
I'm guessing that SIVP is a worst-case problem because of **'any'**.

If it is correct,  does

"For a given **'randomly'** chosen lattice basis **B**, it is hard to find n linearly independent short vectors in **L(B)**"

is an average-case problem?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  To solve SIVP, an algorithm must work for *any* given input basis $B$.  One can also formulate an average-case variant of SIVP, where the input basis is generated at random according to some probability distribution.